# [Linux, Ubuntu]: Executing a Python script with different users results in different behaviours

Tags: php, python, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to execute a script in Ubuntu with Python with my user "ubuntu". It's a virtual machine of Amazon, so I'm trying to execute that code

```
$execQuery = "python script.py";
exec($execQuery, $output, $return);
```

by executing that command with **ubuntu** the results is **OK**, but executing it from PHP (which user is **www-data**), I get:

> ImportError: No module named skimage.io

So I think there's an error about permission, but since I've never used Python, I don't know where I have to put the right permissions.

Does anyone have a clue?

Thank you very much.

---

I've tried to use `pip install ___ --user www-data` but didn't work either.

Comment: Your python modules are installed under differenct user, so when you launch python as www-data python can't find them. I guess you have to launch your script as a user, whom those modules where installed to

Comment: `pip install ___ --user www-data` with `sudo` I suppose...

Comment: nope, already tried :\

Comment: What does your python path look like?

Comment: Looks fine since when I execute if from user "ubuntu" works. $PYTHONPATH=/home/ubuntu/python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is weird, while it was working from the main user, it wasn't working from **www-data**.

The problem, obviously was in the sckit-image Python module and I thought it was a **permission problem**. In fact, the **www-data** user wasn't locating the right library even if I set the `$PYTHONPATH` and y tried to import it as well from the script as:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "path/to/python");
```

but nothing happened.

When installing the scikit-image. There was an error on the **scipy** which was giving me at the same time an error with **gfortran**.

`sudo apt-get install gfortran` and reinstalling **scipy** and **scikit-image** resolved the problem.